# How can i apply a style or a category to mailbox emails when message flag answered is applied in Mailkit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I use MailKit to read messages from a Various Mailboxes. Works great..
How can i apply a style or a category to mailbox emails when message flag answered is applied?I can´t seem to find anything about it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "style" or "category"? These do not sound like things that IMAP supports, but maybe you are just using the wrong terminology.

Comment: I want the mail that are processed in mailbox to either assign a category or have a flag sort of that is visible to users to know it is processed. I do assign answered flag but that is not something visible to users.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP does not have a concept of categories or styles. This is up to the user's mail client to synthesize by either setting custom flags on the message(s) (assuming that the IMAP server supports custom flags) or by just storing those attributes somehow locally on the user's desktop (or mobile device).

In your follow-up comment, you explain that what you want is a flag that users can see in their mail client. Again, this all depends on what mail client that they are using. Some clients will display the "Answered" flag and others might not. It might also depend on which message-list columns the user has enabled.

I guess you could try setting the `MessageFlags.Flagged` flag. That's one flag I know of that is displayed by all of the mail clients I've ever used.